# eliminate user name prompt on login screen

Tags: login, password

I have two machines both running 20.04.     On one of them, I'm prompted for my user name, on the other the only prompt is for my password.     I'm the only nonroot user in /etc/passwd.      There was another subdirectory in /home---/home/leo, but there was never a separate user associated with that directory;   it was a directory inherited from a previous installation.

So I deleted /home/simon  and now /home contains just me i.e., /home/simon.   But that didn't eliminate the username prompt.     How would I convince ubuntu that there is only one user, and so go straight to a password prompt?     Thanks!

Comment: I edited the question.    I'm the only user other than root on the machine

Comment: I doubt there is logic built in to detect this edge case.

Answer (score 0):

You can set autologin if you are the only user by editing the configuration file of your default display manager - lxdm, sddm, gdm3, etc. In the file lxdm.conf or sddm.conf edit autologin user=your user name. This way you will not be asked for either the password or the user name at login.

Comment: I'm reluctant to eliminate the password for security reasons, would just like to eliminate the username prompt